# How do I remove the selected tab indicator from the TabWidget?

Tags: android

Here's what I'd like to remove :

[image]

How do I replace the indicator showing which tab is currently shown as well as the blue line that spans the entire tabwidget?

To Specify: All I want indicating which tab is selected is this :

- tab_button_active.9.png should be shown as background if the tab is SELECTED
- tab_button_inactive.9.png should be shown as the background if the tab is NOT SELECTED.

edit : Setting tabStripEnabled to false has no effect. Adding a style to it and having "@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar" as its parent is also not possible since im targetting API level 7 and the ActionBar was implemented in API level 11.

Comment: You can customize everything about the actionbar. There is a good tutorial [here.](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) And a similar question [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14589743/2015318)

Comment: Did you try this stackoverflow post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240756/android-how-to-remove-selected-tab-highlight-color-on-press-highlight-on-tabw

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If `android:tabStripEnabled="false"` did not work then I also assume calling `setStripEnabled(boolean stripEnabled)` will have no effect as well. If all of this is true then your problem is probably not in TabWidget.

I would suggest looking at your tab indicator. Try these modifications. This code is taken from a fragment that has tabs.

Here is the code that creates the tab indicator view.

```
    View indicator = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab,
(ViewGroup) mRoot.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs), false);

        TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag);
        tabSpec.setIndicator(indicator);
        tabSpec.setContent(tabContentId);
```

Your tab indicator view would probably like similar to this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/tabselector"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/tab1icon"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the important part here is the `android:background="@drawable/tabselector"` in the LinearLayout. Mine looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_light" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_light" />
    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focused_light" />
    <!-- Pressed state -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_pressed_light" />
</selector>
```

This tabselector.xml is where you will swap `@drawable/tab_pressed_light` with your `@drawable/tab_button_active` and `@drawable/tab_unselected_light` with `@drawable/tab_button_inactive`

Be sure to check that all of your drawables that go into your tabselector.xml do not have the blue strips along the bottom. As I look at your image I can see little 5px gaps along that strip this is what gave me the idea that the strip was not from your TabWidget. Hope this helps.

Comment: android:tabStripEnabled="false" was not available for me. I instead had to use app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"

Answer (score 45):

This line **`app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"`** solve the problem for me in xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_bottom_tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"             //this line
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Answer (score 41):

I have yet another hack.

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(0);
```

It's basically the same idea as Eleojasmil's.

Comment: Now java says  ```tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(0)``` method deprecated.

Comment: deprecated now - use color changing.

Answer (score 17):

For `TabLayout`:
Just Use `app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_album_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabPadding="@dimen/common_margin" />
```

Answer (score 9):

Add this to your `TabLayout XML`:

```
app:tabIndicator="@null"
```

Answer (score 7):

there is one line answer to that
you have only to change the color of the indicator into a transparent

color.xml

```
 <color name="transparent2">#00000000</color>
```

and put this line to your tabwidget

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent2));
```

or

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/transparent2"
```

Comment: for transparent color: android.R.color.transparent

Answer (score 6):

Try setting the Tab indicator height to zero:

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(0);
```

Comment: Good job repeating my answer :)

Comment: It's now deprecated

Comment: deprecated now - use color changing.

Answer (score 4):

Use `tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicator(0)`.

`tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(0)` is now deprecated and `tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` won't perform as well because it uses transparency.

Answer (score 4):

Use this `app:tabIndicator="@null"`

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicator="@null"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicator(null);
```

This will set the selected indicator drawable to null.

Answer (score 2):

Set  attribute  `android:tabStripEnabled="false"` for your `TabWidget`.

Comment: setting android:tabStripEnabled="false" in the TabWidget has no effect.

Comment: Oh..too bad.. try `android:tabStripEnabled="false"
            android:alpha="0" `

Comment: That would make the entire tabwidget transparent

Comment: Then I would need to try it out myself and get back to you. Sorry for the disappointment.

Answer (score 2):

I looked for a long time to remove the ugly holo menu bar
tried everything. accidentally used this code for another reason and it thank god removed it.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {          
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); // unselected
        TextView tv = (TextView)tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); //Unselected Tabs
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    }
```

Source: [Android tabhost change text color style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533061/android-tabhost-change-text-color-style)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this method on your tablayout to hide the tab indicator.

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

here what I use, since the `tabIndicator.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(0);` is depcrecated

use  `tabIndicator.setSelectedTabIndicator(0);`

Answer (score 1):

For the best setting `app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use  app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/transparent_color", it'll work 100%

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using ActionBarSherlock. The problem with using a TabWdiget is, that it is not part of ABS, so it will look "native" for each Android Version. For me, the best approach for tab navigtion with ABS is to use a ViewPager and ViewPagerIndicator and style the indicator. Downside is, that your tabs must be fragments. If you need your tabs to be activities then you should take a look if the guys at HoloEveryhwhere have managed to add the TabWidget.

Comment: I'm not using ABS. Simply the v4 support library.

Comment: Either way, you don't need ABS for my approach. I mentioned it because it works with ABS.

Comment: I think you missed the part that you provide a solution for the OPs question.

Answer (score -2):

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tabcolor));
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tabcolor));
```

[More info here](http://helptodevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/09/how-do-i-remove-selected-tab-indicator.html)