# how to remove bottom space from tabwidgets in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

i have tried to remove spaces from bottom of tabs.
[screen shot of space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R77sO.png)

```
Here is my xml code.
```

I want to remove that space below green color of my tab.

enter code here

```
                   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:showDividers="none"
                android:tabStripEnabled="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

i have search so much but not getting proper solution.

I want to remove that space below green color of my tab.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: try android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: i am using Linear layout as a parent layout, so can not use
"android:layout_alignParentBottom="true""

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:tabStripEnabled="false"`

Comment: on second note, if tat did not work try reading accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672302/how-do-i-remove-the-selected-tab-indicator-from-the-tabwidget