# Customize view pager android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-styles, viewpagerindicator

i am trying to implement a view pager with indicator like in the image bellow. The problem is that i can't manage to style the indicator in order to look like that.
[image]

Could someone tell me how can i obtain that indicator because using the normal one will give me something like 
[image]

I have tried to change the style but will only change to the size of the tab, not smaller than that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend to you to see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRg_eDfQ8fk&list=UUVHFbqXqoYvEWM1Ddxl0QDg) tutorial about sliding tabs.

if this not what u looking for u can create your own tabs layout and implement OnPageChangeListener, when the method "onPageSelected" invoked u can  change the visibility of the indicator in your custom tab layout.

Comment: Hi @Liran. Thank you for your support. Right now the tutorial provides only a part of the solution, the sliding one. The other problem is how can i make de design of the underlying to be slimmer. i've tried to generate a custom tab but they have the same height. Is there a way to make it slimmer or only if i make my custom underlying bar??

Comment: look this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15261139/1928342 it's seems like u can to set your own background for the tab, attention to the selector, when the view in state 'android:state_selected="true"' you should set 'android:drawable="@drawable/your_custom_drawable_with_padding_underline"