# Change the actionbar colors from blue to orange

Tags: android, android-actionbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the style of action bar API 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589671/how-can-i-change-the-style-of-action-bar-api-15)

I want to change the action bar colors from blue to orange to be as following photo
How can I do that? 
[image]

Comment: it's not that hard really see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044303/actionbarsherlock-change-actionbar-line-colour

Comment: haven't you asked this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save yourself a lot of work and use the Action Bar Style Generator:
http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator

While you're at it, check out the holo theme generator:
http://android-holo-colors.com/